# Razor columns define

Tags: razor

My razor code, create this layout.

[image]

but I don't like this **position**. I would something like this.

[image]

How can I create something like image above ?

This is my razor code.

```
     <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @using (DAEF.DA_Mit daef = new DAEF.DA_Mit())
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                          model => model.CodMit,
                          new SelectList(daef.SelectAll(), "CodMit", "ItemPerDropdown"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        }
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodMit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>


                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodCreator, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @using (DAEF.DA_Mit daef = new DAEF.DA_Mit())
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                            model => model.CodCreator,
                            new SelectList(daef.SelectAll(), "CodMit", "ItemPerDropdown"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        }
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodMit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Info, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Info, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 4 })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Info, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Is there anyone who can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
```

has to be

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
```

and the other two

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

have to be

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```

And also make two seperated groups instead of two nested groups

More about the grid-system used: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/